# Estimate Beta of CAPM from Implied Volatility?

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, correlation, beta, capm

In the CAPM theory Beta of asset $i$ are estimated in this way:

$ \beta_i = \frac{\sigma_{im}}{\sigma^2_m} $
where $\sigma_{im} = \rho_{im} \sigma_i \sigma_m$

But all these data are historical data. So, I'm wondering what if I use

- $\sigma^2_m$ <- **Implied volatility** of SP500 (VIX)
- $\sigma_{im}$ <- **implied volatility** for the asset $i$ using the at-the-money call option with a 1-month maturity.
- $\rho_{im}$ will be statistically estimated.

This way is a better estimation of the $\beta_{i}$ for the next month?

Comment: There's a number of papers on using option-implied betas to explain the stock returns.

Comment: There are methods of calculating option implied correlation as well for certain equities.  See here: https://www.cboe.com/micro/impliedcorrelation/impliedcorrelationindicator.pdf

Comment: @sparkle, it would be very good to get your feedback on the answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is a better way. 
Just take a look to figure 3, from Buss and Vilkov (2012, RFS):
[image]